# How Do You Add Packages To AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, npm, gruntjs, jqvmap

So currently, I thought I'd have a go at teaching myself AngularJS and NPM. Using Professional AngularJS by Diego Netto and Valeri Karpov as a guide, which I hope isn't a bad book for the language, I managed to get as far as installing the application using Yeoman and then using Grunt to run it.

The problem is, where I'm up to in the book, really doesn't explain how to add third party packages from the NPM site. So I'm trying to install the package 'jqvmap' as jquery is already installed already and seems to be working. I've got as far as using the 'npm i jqvmap' command to install the package using NPM and the bash console shows it as installed, but I have no clue on how to actually add the damn thing to my project.

So can anybody knowledge in Angular help me here? As this is my first time using a proper JS Framework for webapps and I really have no clue on how to add a package - As basic as this probably is to do.

I already have the package in the package.json dependencies, but it won't appear in the actual app itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can add other modules to your module in angular place where you created your module.

```
var project = angular.module("project",["aModule", "anotherModule"]);
```